# XAML canvas.top works, but canvas.bottom doesn't in visual studio (chrome)

Tags: xaml, canvas, visual-studio-2012

I am currently learning XAML but I've encountered an annoying problem.
When I use canvas.top... on a border in my file it works (running via chrome in 
visual studio, I will add some interactivity using js) but when I use
canvas.bottom nothing happens (just a white screen). What am I doing wrong?

Code using top + image:
http://oi47.tinypic.com/1zxm9td.jpg, http://pastebin.com/XqLeiK7j

Code using bottom:

```
<Border Background="#FF0093DD" BorderThickness="1" Canvas.Bottom="50" 
        Canvas.Left="80" Height="25" Width="200">
   <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="center" TextAlignment="center" 
              FontSize="10" Foreground="White">N° of correct responses</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

If I use another software, called kaxaml the .bottom option works, but I really
want to know why it doesn't in visual studio 2012

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canvas.Bottom property is supported for [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas_attachedproperties.aspx) but not for [Windows Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209267.aspx) or [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas_attachedproperties%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) apps.